# Add attribute to every tag in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-mixin

I have a vue project with a lot of `<img` tags inside of my template. There're a lot of components with even more images. Now I want to disable drag for them all.

The first thing that comes to mind is to grep files for `<img` tags and add `draggable="false"` to every image inside of every  template.

I wonder if I can do this in one place, like in global mixin or something.

Comment: This is one of those, "Man...I wish I would've made a component for that!" moments.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've never thought I would need to make a component for `<img` tag, do you? But I guess that's how I resolve this issue.

Comment: I would absolutely use a component for this so you can make tons of global modifications easily. Or add/toggle new properties/flags.

Comment: `img {pointer-events: none;}` should do the trick. Feel free to change the selector to match your requirements. A JS alternative would be to add an event listener on `dragstart` and call `.preventDefault()` on it. Please show us what you tried and add a link to any documentation which led you to believe it should work.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to register an event listener for the `dragstart` event on the document element and prevent the drag operation if an `<img>` was the target:

```es6
document.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this on your mounted hooks:

```
mounted(){
    this.$nextTick(()=>{
       let allimages = document.querySelectorAll("img");
       for (var i = 0;i < allimages.length; i++){
          allimages[i].setAttribute("draggable", "false");
        }
    })
} // end of mounted hook
```

Comment: Where do you put it? In global mixin? Then `updated` is the appropriate place, coz image could be rendered with `if`. querying document for every update is not the solution

Comment: Can you place the bit of code that renders the images?

Comment: `<template><div><img v-if="a" /></div>`, `<script> setTimeout(() => a = true, 100)</script>`

Comment: Why don't you just add __draggable="false"__  to the template 

    <template><div><img v-if="a" draggable="false" /></div>, <script> setTimeout(() => a = true, 100)</script>

Comment: Because I have 100 templates and 100 images in every?

Comment: Are they nested inside a parent component? If so you could use props.